# suming columns basis the condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id        amt_1          amt_2          final_1          
01        23             23               29               
02        30             0                30               
03         0             0                10               
04        10             0                10
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id        amt_1          amt_2          final_1          final_2
01        23             23               29               29
02        30             0                30               60
03         0             0                10               10
04        10             0                10               20
```

**final_2 = final_1 + amt_1(only if amt_2 == 0)**

Approach used :

```
df['final_2'] = df[['amt_1','final_1']].sum(axis=1).where(df['amt_2'] == 0, 0)
```

not getting the expected output with the same. any leads.?

Comment: No problem if change types of integers to floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for the condition, and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) with a `fill_value=0` to handle the NaNs:

```
df['final_2'] = df['final_1'].add(df['amt_1'].where(df['amt_2'].eq(0)), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   Id  amt_1  amt_2  final_1  final_2
0   1     23     23       29     29.0
1   2     30      0       30     60.0
2   3      0      0       10     10.0
3   4     10      0       10     20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `amt_1` to `0` by condition in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['final_2'] = df['final_1'].add(df['amt_1'].where(df['amt_2'] == 0, 0))

print (df)
   Id  amt_1  amt_2  final_1  final_2
0   1     23     23       29       29
1   2     30      0       30       60
2   3      0      0       10       10
3   4     10      0       10       20
```

Or:

```
df['final_2'] = df['final_1'] + df['amt_1'].where(df['amt_2'] == 0, 0)

print (df)
   Id  amt_1  amt_2  final_1  final_2
0   1     23     23       29       29
1   2     30      0       30       60
2   3      0      0       10       10
3   4     10      0       10       20
```